# assign keybinding to windows terminal profile

Tags: windows, key-binding, windows-terminal

I would like to assign to one of the new windows terminal profiles a keybinding, as in the following (**`"keys": "alt+shift+d"`**):

```
        {
            // Connects to a remote machine using SSH
            "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
            "name":  "SSH My Local Server",
            "tabTitle": "Local Server",
            "commandline": "ssh eddy@flyer.local",
            "keys": "alt+shift+d"
        },
```

what is the way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `keys` property in [Profile settings in Windows Terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings). However, you can create [custom key bindings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/terminal/customize-settings/key-bindings) (keyboard shortcuts) inside Windows Terminal that give you control of how you interact with the terminal using your keyboard.

The <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> shortcut is (by default) dedicated to open a new pane - as you can see in the corresponding part of `settings.json`:

```
// Add custom keybindings to this array.
// To unbind a key combination from your defaults.json, set the command to "unbound".
// To learn more about keybindings, visit https://aka.ms/terminal-keybindings
"keybindings":
[
    // Copy and paste are bound to Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V in your defaults.json.
    // These two lines additionally bind them to Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.
    // To learn more about selection, visit https://aka.ms/terminal-selection
    { "command": {"action": "copy", "singleLine": false }, "keys": "ctrl+c" },
    { "command": "paste", "keys": "ctrl+v" },

    // Press Ctrl+Shift+F to open the search box
    { "command": "find", "keys": "ctrl+shift+f" },

    // Press Alt+Shift+D to open a new pane.
    // - "split": "auto" makes this pane open in the direction that provides the most surface area.
    // - "splitMode": "duplicate" makes the new pane use the focused pane's profile.
    // To learn more about panes, visit https://aka.ms/terminal-panes
    { "command": { "action": "splitPane", "split": "auto", "splitMode": "duplicate" }, "keys": "alt+shift+d" }
]
```

You can delete this keyboard shortcut here and add appropriate part from the following *[default binding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/terminal/customize-settings/key-bindings#new-tab)* schema, for instance (if your `"SSH My Local Server"` is the 3rd entry in the [profile list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings))

```
{ "command": { "action": "newTab", "index": 2 }, "keys": "alt+shift+d" },
```